# Recommended way to let PHP communicate with a process on the same server

Tags: php, c++

I wrote a communication software in C++ (named "talkto"). Now I want to access this program via a website in php. The problem is, that the webcode has to interact with the program. So start program and look at the result after the program stops is no way. For e.g. you can start my process with the parameter:

```
talkto.exe enum receiver
```

the program will broadcast a udp package and wait for answers. Unfortunately this will block the PHP script until the program exits. Also, talkto will establish a kind of session to the receiver, which is only valid during running. Once part of the enumeration, a receiver can change his state and announce it to talkto. I have little knowledge of PHP. What I need is a kind of website, showing the receiver and update if a state changes. I got total control of talkto, so I can use stdio, sockets or pipes. The Webserver is an Apache. The program will/has to run on the same machine. Security is a issue.

Comment: I think the key is in that _PHP blocks_, anything that blocks can not interact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using Message Queue (I think anything with MQ-suffix will do, ActiveMQ, RabbitMQ, ZeroMQ), your 2 distinct processes can communicate via messages passing through MQ

Another option for linking 2 processes is to use Redis (Pub/Sub)

About the later problem, it is the nature of PHP to block code. There is one simple way to get around this which is to use external queue for PHP (I am using this https://github.com/chrisboulton/php-resque)

Basically, your PHP script will push some tasks into the queue, then the tasks will be eventually executed which will prevent the code from being blocked due to long execution

Comment: I looked deeper into ZeroMQ. I think this will do the job. Thx